# Sum index in a Recursive Procedure Call in Maple

Tags: reference-request, summation, recursion, maple, programming

I'm trying to reproduce Buchholz Polynomials in Maple as outlined by J. Sesma and J. Abad in [their](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82650166.pdf) paper (equation 14).

The definition given above is a recursive one and so is the code I've created in Maple. I run into problems when using the index of the `sum()` command in the recursive call. The MWE that produces this error is:

```
P0 := 1:
P := []:

Pz := proc(n, b, z, P, P0)
        local exp1, exp2, k;
        option trace;
        exp1 := (2*k-1)*(2^(2*k)*bernoulli(2*k))/factorial(2*k);
        exp2 := (2^(2*k)*bernoulli(2*k))/factorial(2*k);
        print(n);
        if n <= 0 then
                return P0;
        else
                return [op(P), (z/2)*sum(exp1*thisproc(n-2*k+1,b,z,P,P0),k=1..(n+1)/2) + (b-2)*sum(exp2*thisproc(n-2*k,b,z,P,P0),k=1..n/2)];
        end if:
end proc:

Pz(1,b,z,P,P0);
```

The error I get is:

`Error, (in Pz) cannot determine if this expression is true or false: -2*k <= -2`

Which I believe suggests the `sum()` command is not passing the current value of the indexing variable `k` as the `sum()` command runs the recursive call.

Based on the definition provided by J. Sesma and J. Abad I would expect that `P[1]=z/6`.

Comment: Does it know if $k$ is positive or negative?

Comment: based on the error it seems that *k* is unassigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do by having it return a list.

But as far as the use of the index `k` goes, perhaps this is what you're after.

```
restart;
P0 := 1:
P := []:

Pz := proc(n, b, z, P, P0) #option trace;
  local exp1, exp2, k;
  exp1 := (2*k-1)*(2^(2*k)*bernoulli(2*k))/factorial(2*k);
  exp2 := (2^(2*k)*bernoulli(2*k))/factorial(2*k);
  if n <= 0 then
    return P0;
  else
    return (z/2)*add(eval(exp1,k=kk)
                     *thisproc(n-2*kk+1,b,z,P,P0),
                     kk=1..(n+1)/2)
           + (b-2)*add(eval(exp2,k=kk)
                       *thisproc(n-2*kk,b,z,P,P0),
                       kk=1..n/2);
  end if:
end proc:

Pz(1,b,z,P,P0):

        1/6*z

Pz(2,b,z,P,P0):

    1/36*z^2+1/3*b-2/3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! 

I'm pretty new to working with maple, I don't suppose in your answer you could add a little explanation of what I did wrong or why it didn't work or how your working solution corrected the problems in my original problem?

Comment: The `sum` command uses Maple's usual evaluation model in which arguments are evaluated up front, ie. before `sum` starts its work. So the call to `thisproc` evaluated up front using the `k` that is local to your `Pz`. In contrast, the `add` command has so-called special-evaluation-rules and defers the evaluation of the call to `thisproc` until after the call to `thisproc` gets the instance of the `k` (or `kk`) instantiated using the values of the summation indexing variable. I tried to make this clearer by using an ostensibly different name (`kk` vs `k`).